# swift error : Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift

i think login but can not resolve [responseString]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Update your question with the actual text of your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're missing the argument label. Try:

```
NSURL(string: secureData)
```